# url rewrite messes up php

Tags: php, .htaccess, dynamic, url-rewriting

i have this url rewrite for a calendar on my website. this is the code:

```
RewriteRule ^calendar/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})$ /calendar/?year=$1&month=$1
```

so that i can just use domain.com/calendar/yyyy/mm instead. the problem is that it messes up all the images, css, php, etc files on the page. i added this to the head and that fixes the css and images:

```
<base href="http://www.domain.com/">
```

but the calendar is still broken. i tried this which i saw as an answer on another similar question but it didnt do anything. any ideas how to fix this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) calendar/?year=$1&month=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you're using **relative links** in your css/js/images.

You need to make sure to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: the problem is with the calendar. the previous/next month buttons dont work. the events are not on the calendar. and even if i change the month in the url it goes to the wrong month, it always says october even if i go to domain.com/2014/XX